# Android Constraint layout bottom element overlaps when keyboard pops up

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In Constraint layout, Its a form with name,address,country,city,zip,state and save button with app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" constraint at the bottom. But save button overlaps state input field when keyboard pops up.

The button view should always stick to bottom it can't constraint to other views.

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/c_billing_address_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".activities.subscription.ui.fragments.BillingAddressFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edt_in_name"
            style="@style/Widget.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_name"
                style="@style/Widget.EditTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/name_hint_label"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edt_in_address"
            style="@style/Widget.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edt_in_name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_address"
                style="@style/Widget.EditTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/address_hint_label"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edt_in_country"
            style="@style/Widget.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edt_in_address">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_country"
                style="@style/Widget.EditTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/county_hint_label"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

            android:id="@+id/edt_in_city"
            style="@style/Widget.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edt_in_country">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_city"
                style="@style/Widget.EditTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/city_hint_label" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edt_in_zip"
            style="@style/Widget.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edt_in_city">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_zip"
                style="@style/Widget.EditTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/zip_hint_label"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

            android:id="@+id/edt_in_state"
            style="@style/Widget.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edt_in_zip">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_state"
                style="@style/Widget.EditTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/province_hint_label"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            style="@style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save_label"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <include layout="@layout/progress_bar_layout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, rearrange your scrollable and non-scrollable elements like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollViewInitialCompanySelection"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonSave"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutInitialCompanySelection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--            <your scrollable views here>-->

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save &amp; Continue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the project AndroidManifest.xml corresponding in the file `<activity/>` Tag add the following properties

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will Overlap because your `save button` is not constraint with `state field`, your `save button` is constraint with `parent bottom` so when your `keyboard` popups then your `parent bottom` is top of the `keyboard` you should use:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/edt_state"
```

then it will always under that `state` field along under editText of `state` field.
You can also add this button field in different layout with relative  `bottom` to other layout.

Comment: But I always want to put save button at the bottom of the layout.

Comment: then you should put that button outside `scrollview` oviously  then you need a parent loyout then